# css3 transform perspective and skew failed

Tags: javascript, css

```css
#box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
    transform: perspective( 150px ) rotateY( 45deg );
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
  left:140px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/A4VH0LQ.jpg">

<div id="box"></div>
```

Try to make a box and map it into the billboard but failed. Can't master rotate and perspective properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, and as such shouldn't try answering, but I figured why not? So try this:

```
#box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  transform: perspective( 150px ), rotateY( 45deg );
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
  left:140px;
}
```

Your code snippet was missing a comma in-between the perspective and rotateY transform properties.